# Get biggest coherent area

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have images likes this: [image]

My data consists of numpy matrizes whereas white is represented by 1 and black by 0. I want to extract the body in these images. I can assume that the body is always the biggest coherent area in the image.

Is there an existing algorithm or should I create my own?

Comment: you should explore OpenCV. You can play with morphological operations and then findcountours funtion. Each contour can be isolated, or filtered by area, etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use [`skimage.measure`](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.measure.html) 's  `label` and `regionprops` for two methods. Thus, with `im` as the `2D` input image, we would have those as listed below.

**Approach #1** With `label` and `numpy.bincount` -

```
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops

l = label(im)
out = (l==np.bincount(l.ravel())[1:].argmax()+1).astype(int)
```

**Approach #2** With `label` and `regionprops` -

```
r = regionprops(l) # l is from previous approach
out = (l==(1+np.argmax([i.area for i in r]))).astype(int)
```

Output with given sample -

[image]